# Running Nutch 1.6 on Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, nutch, hadoop-yarn

Has anyone tried running Nutch 1.6 on Hadoop 2.2.0?

I tried running it out of the box and the first problem I got was with the Injector showing the following errors:

```
ERROR crawl.Injector: Injector: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:     
hdfs://................., expected: file:///
```

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: get the same problem :(